# Display Wicket panel content as tooltip on mouse hover of a page component

Tags: jquery, wicket

I have a wicket MultiLineLabel which has its contents coming from database. Now I need to display this MultiLineLabel text as a tooltip on hover of a  on a page.

Can you please suggest me how I should go about this (i am new to wicket). Should i be going with jquery solution or I should go with adding `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` `AjaxEventBehaviors` on my page?

When I tried the [jquery solution](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/) I do not know how can i maintain the line breaks in the tooltip.

Please provide me with any examples you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this with a standard label and it works:

```
Label ml;
String msg = "Hello! \n I'm here.";
add(ml = new Label("multiline",msg));
ml.add(AttributeModifier.append("title", msg));
```

**UPDATED**

Unfortunately it's not possible to control the style of the tooltip generated with the attribute 'title' because it's a OS native component. However you could easily adapt the code you have found at http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/.
You can put the text of the tooltip in a custom attribute, let's call it 'toolTipText':

```
String tooltipMsg = Strings.toMultilineMarkup(yourMsgFromDb).toString(); 
...
yourLabel.add(AttributeModifier.append("toolTipText", tooltipMsg));
```

Please note that you must use  toMultilineMarkup to maintain the line breaks in the tooltip.
Now you should slightly modify function showTooltip to use the value inserted into the custom attribute:

```
var showTooltip = function(event) {
  $('div.tooltip').remove();

  $('<div class="tooltip">' + $(this).attr('toolTipText') +'</div>')
            .appendTo('body');

  changeTooltipPosition(event);
};
```

Finally, you have to tell JQuery to use tooltip with your tag. You must replace "span#hint,label#username'" with the selector matching your component.

I've tested and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. Before I mark this as answer can you please suggest if I can apply cutom CSS to the tooltip created using "title" attribute (similar to the .tooltip style in the example URL above)? I would also be testing it.

Comment: Hi Andrea, one follow up question. When I was actually implementing I came across this issue that how I could display on html. I am using something like following:  <span class="hint" wicket:id="multiLineLabel"></span>. no text is getting displayed as in the code i haven't assigned any text to the label, i assigned it to the new attribute. now can you give me an example on how can i display say an image using css for this span. is there any other way?

Comment: Well, I'm very far from being a CSS guru :), but this article was very helpful to me when I wanted to learn how to display picturs with css:

http://css.dzone.com/news/css-message-boxes-different-me

Comment: the issue is i need to display the toopltip on hover of an image

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand the problem. do you have to use tooltip with an img tag? It should wotk the same way as for span tag.
Anyway, I've realized that I missed one step to do in my last answer. Now I'm gonna add it.